# RevokeAuthorization in new JavaScript Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook

what is the right way to do revokeAuthorization in new Javascript SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as javascript sdk allows us to makes API calls to the Graph API or Deprecated REST API via the FB.api method, you can revoke Authorization via invoking the auth.revokeAuthorization old rest api method.

you can refer to the following fb doc for the usage of FB.api and auth.revokeAuthorization:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.revokeAuthorization/

Comment: The revokeAuthorization link is invalid.